# Make sure the user enters a valid floating-point number in C

Tags: beginner, c, validation, error-handling, floating-point

I would like to know if this is a good way to make sure the user enters a valid number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void clear_stream(FILE *in)
{
   int ch;
   clearerr(in);

   do
      ch = getc(in);
   while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);

   clearerr(in);
}

float retreive_input()
{
    float input = 0;
    fflush(stdout);
    while (scanf_s("%f", &input) != 1)
    {
        clear_stream(stdin);
        printf("Invalid number. Please try again: ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return input;
}

int main()
{
    float input = 0;
    printf("ENTER A NUMBER: ");
    input = retreive_input();
    printf("YOUR INPUT: %f", input);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to define what 'valid input' is.  For example, are: "4.22Rubbish" and "4.22.33.44.55" valid inputs?  They're both recognised as 4.22 by your existing code.  Is this correct?

Comment: @forsvarir I never thought of that, no those aren't valid I just really wouldn't know how to handle those kinds of input. Would you have any suggestions for how to approach those inputs to catch the errors? Thank you!

Comment: @chris360 The only reasonable way I know of approaching those errors is to read the whole line in, then validate the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

[@Justin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140237/make-sure-the-user-enters-a-valid-floating-point-number-in-c#comment262616_140237) advice is solid.  Read a line.

1. `scanf_s("%f", &input)` offers no advantage over the more portable `scanf("%f", &input)`
2. `scanf_s/scanf("%f", &input)` allows the user to enter multiple lines before the number - so a blank line of input is not detected.
3. `scanf_s/scanf("%f", &input)` does not detect trailing non-numeric input.
4. `while (scanf_s("%f", &input) != 1)` does not cope with non-numeric entries - they remain in `stdin`.
5. Overflow is UB with `scanf()` and friends.

Instead separate the task: input, parsing.

```
#define MAXLINE_SIZE 100
char buf[MAXLINE_SIZE];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();

size_t len = strlen(buf);
if (len == 0 || buf[len-1] != '\n') {
  // consider the line hostile and fail it.
  // consume rest of line
  clear_stream(stdin);
  return FAIL;
}
```

Parse using `strtod()` - Simple example.  Additional considerations if over/underflow detection needed.

```
errno = 0;
char *endptr;
float y = (float) strtod(buf, &endptr);

if (buf == endptr) Handle_NoConversion();
// consume trailing spaces
while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr) endptr++;
if (*endptr) Handle_TrailingJunk(). 

// Good to go;
return y;
```

Good use of `fflush(stdout);` before input and after the re-prompt that may lack a `\n`.  I would not hard code in the re-prompt value, but pass it in.

Good use of `int ch;` when testing the return value of `getc()`.

Using `%f` to print floating point is problematic should the `float` be small (output only `0.000000`) or large (many to hundreds of digits).  Consider [%.*e](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)